# Sending both a String and a Byte[] from Android app to Python Server over Sockets

Tags: java, python, android, sockets, networking

I'm sending an image from an android app as a byte array. I was previously able to send the array in parts and then put those parts into a list in python but that created some errors because python would front load each part with b' and those would remain as part of the string. So I'm now trying to send the entire byte array. Before I send the array I send a String that gives the size of the Byte array so I can call call .recv for the proper size.

```
bytes_len = int(clean_len(str(connection.recv(1024))))
```

Where clean_len just takes out '\'' and 'b'

I then use 
`data = connection.recv(int(bytes_len)`
But it outputs data as

```
Waiting on connection...
---------------------------------------------
Connection Accepted
Connection received from... ('192.168.1.89', 41568)
BYTES_LEN_RECV:  9640320 
METADATA_RECV:  m240,second_attempt,requalify,4,4,4
BYTE_ARRAY_RECV:  b'' #THIS IS THE ISSUE
Sending Response
Closing Connection to  ('192.168.1.89', 41568)
```

I'm sending the string like this from the app, it's closely followed by the byte array

```
printWriter.write(String.valueOf(bytes.length));
printWriter.flush();
printWriter.write(metadata);
printWriter.flush();
printWriter.close();

BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
bufferedOutputStream.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
bufferedOutputStream.flush();
bufferedOutputStream.close();
socket.close();
```

Can you just not send byte arrays that long? Or am I missing some crucial unknown step?

Comment: I'd start by checking the raw data before any processing is done, ie before `clean_len`. I also think that the first `recv` is reading the buffer so when the second `recv` is called, all that has been already read, which yields an empty array.

Comment: Oh I'd assumed each .recv corresponded to each call to .flush in the app. I used two calls for the metadata and the size like so
```
bytes_len = int(clean_len(str(connection.recv(1024))))
metadata = clean_len(str(connection.recv(1024)))
```

Comment: Try it out and let me know if that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't read the socket multiple times. Refactor the code so you take the raw bytes from the buffer first, then process the bytes any way that you like.

```
data = connection.recv(1024)
data = clean_data(data)
...
```

Comment: Changed it so the processing was done afterwards and there was no change.
To make the protocol clear it goes
One call to .recv(1024) to get the length of the byte array
Another call to .recv(1024) to get some metadata (Also a string)
and then a final call to .recv(length) to get the byte array

The first two calls work fine, it's only the byte array part

Comment: I think you want to refactor your communication because it seems like you are under the impression that you are controlling the information being sent by calling `flush`. Think of the socket as a constant stream of bytes, and you can't depend on `flush` the way that you are. There are multiple ways to do this. Some ideas:  1) Parsing the data on the receiver side 2) Make the messages constant length (by padding) and receive by reading the previously known size. 3) Send a JSON array `{"metadata": "", "data": ""}` and check on server until a complete JSON array is received then `json.loads`.

Comment: Okay I changed it so I send a JSON Object instead of the two calls for sending the string, but the Byte array still comes up empty.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up just converting the Bytes array to a string object and sending it in a similar way as the metadata and it now all sends as one piece. Thanks for the help!